# Can I pass arguments to a external Beanshell script, sourced from another Beanshell script?

Tags: java, scripting, beanshell

I am trying to figure out how to pass arguments to a second script that I call from an initial script.  The Beanshell documentation says nothing about this.  Does anyone know how to do this?

```
// Start.bsh
import bsh.Interpreter;
Interpreter i = new Interpreter();
i.source("Target.bsh");
```

.

```
// Target.bsh
System.out.println("No. of arguments are: " + args.length);
for(int i= 0;i < args.length;i++) {
  System.out.println("Argument " + i + " is : " + args[i]);
}
```

Comment: if I may, what is the application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK, you can't pass command line parameters through `i.source("file.bsh")`. You'll need to do something like this:

```
Interpreter i = new Interpreter();
NameSpace ns = i.getNameSpace();
ns.setVariable("args", new String[]{"param1", "param2"}, false);
i.source("Target.bsh");
```